# C# How many times should I raise the PropertyChanged event

Tags: c#, events, methods, propertychanged

Say I have a method that removes a single child from a parent object and raises a PropertyChanged event to indicate that the list of children as changed. Now say that I have a second method that can delete multiple children in one call and that makes use of the first method in order not to write a piece of code a second time. In this case, should I let the second method call the first one N times and raise the PropertyChanged event N times, or should I only raise the event a single time at the end of my second method ? Thank you.

Comment: If you can minimize method calls with the same result, always go for less calls.

Comment: Well I would rather waste a little bit of performance in exchange of having less code to maintain / debug. But I would also like to make sure that it is designed accordingly to the C# philosophy.

Comment: I guess that internally `PropertyChanged` only sets a flag that this object should be updated, so it may not matter anyways.

I guess your code in this context is not time critical?

Comment: Well that entirely depends on how the user of my class designs his event handlers. He can legitimately expect a single event raise for a single method code and rely on that behaviour.

Comment: Extract the code for removing the object from the first method in a helper method and leave the RaisPropertyChangedEvent code in the first method, then use the helpermethod in your bulk remove

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I know how I would proceed if I wanted to raise the event a single time. My question is more : should I make sure it is raised a single time or not ? What would be the proper design ?

Comment: I'd say having a "`NotifyAllHandlers`" method which you call when you've finished calling `NotifyPropertyChanged`, the same pattern as EF uses for `SaveChanges` on the `DbContext`.  I think it's called UnitOfWork pattern.  Winforms also has something similar, a `SuspendLayout` and `ResumeLayout` for when you've finished changing the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a consumer of your component I would expect that the `PropertyChanged` event was raised only once per call I made, whether ultimately that call resulted in one or multiple items to be removed.

As you have stated in your comment, I may be doing complex or relatively long-running processing when I handle the changed event. If I am iterating and doing something with the remaining items and there are a lot of them (hundreds? Thousands?) then having to do that multiple times instead of just once could very quickly snowball and potentially become a serious performance problem.

Comment: Thanks I will go for that.